# versioning a application on mac

Tags: java, macos

I have a java application that i have coded for mac and created a .app file of it.Now what i want to do is as soon as the application is double clicked to start or is run, i want a script to check for a updated version of this .app on the server.(i have the server path of the new .app file).
Please tell me how can i achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `.app` is not a file, it's a folder. Oh and what you want to achieve has to be "coded" in the app, it's an application behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's exactly what you're after but... I'm shipping a Java app as a .dmg (containing a .app folder) on OS X.

Here's what I'm doing: upon starting, the application contacts my server and if there's a new version available, it tells that to the user.  But the application ain't upgrading itself automatically.

Note that you have to be **very** careful with automatic upgrades: if you mess a release and hand out a broken update then things can go very bad very quickly.  This happened to Skype recently and the situation was really quite messy.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Java Web Start for MacOS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/03-JavaDeployment/JavaDeployment.html)

> Mac OS X supports deploying your application as a Java Web Start application. Java Web Start is an implementation of the Java Network Launching Protocol (JNLP) specification, which means that Mac OS X users can run your application in their web browser with a single click. Java Web Start automatically updates your application by checking your website for a new version before launch.

Comment: I disagree... Java as a **very** bad rep on Mac (I'm shipping a Java app on Mac). Basically you really don't want your Mac users to know they're installing a Java app or you'll be losing a big part of your potential users.  Mac users expects a *.dmg* containing a *.app* (and they don't know it: all they want is to see the "drive" and then to drag'n'drop the application from inside the "drive" to the Applications folder).  JWS is a big no-no.

Comment: I agree with Gugussee - don't forget we're dealing with a lot of fanboys here ;)

Comment: It all depends on who your target audience is. If it's an internal app, then a .jnlp file will work just fine. The "fanboys" can be finnicky as there is no real standard way of distributing a MacOS X app, aside from making a .pkg file. And on that note, you could make a .pkg file that installs the .jnlp file and with a post install script that runs the .jnlp the first time